# Типы данных в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, объявление

Какие типы данных можно хранить в массиве? Числа и строки я знаю. А может ли быть элементом массива иконка или файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да конечно вы можете создать какой либо объект класса и сделать из него массив объектов который может содержать "иконки" например.

Например

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class MyClass { 
  int x; 
public: 
  void setX(int i) { x = i; } 
  int getX() { return x; } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
  MyClass obs[4]; 
  int i; 

  for(i=0; i < 4; i++) 
    obs[i].setX(i); 

  for(i=0; i < 4; i++) 
    cout << "obs[" << i << "].getX(): " << obs[i].getX() << "\n"; 

  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Согласно стандарту C++ (8.3.4 Arrays)

> 1 In a declaration T D where D has the form D1
>   attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt and the type of the identiﬁer in the
>   declaration T D1 is “derived-declarator-type-list T”, then the type of
>   the identiﬁer of D is an array type; if the type of the identiﬁer of D
>   contains the auto type-speciﬁer, the program is ill-formed. T is
>   called the array element type; **this type shall not be a reference
>   type, the (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) type void, a function type or an
>   abstract class type.**

Как видно из этой цитаты, вы не можете объявлять массивы ссылочных типов, то есть массивы ссылок, массивы `void` элементов (но можете объявлять массивы указателей на `void`), массивы функций (но можете объявлять массивы указателей на функции) и массивы абстрактных классов.

Поэтому вы можете объявить массив элементов любого класса, в том числе и класса иконок, лишь бы этот класс не был абстрактным.

Answer (score 1):

> Массив – это набор элементов одного типа, доступ к которым
>   производится по индексу – порядковому номеру элемента в массиве.

Массив может состоять из любых типов, начиная стандартными и заканчивая пользовательскими.